# Is there a way to display playa fields inside my matrix field?

Tags: ee2, matrix, playa, custom-fields

I have searched high and low for answers to why my fields are not displaying properly or displaying data I need.

I am basically trying to get the url for the playa entry selected in the backend to the frontend with an anchor.

My template setup is this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="brands" dynamic="no" limit="100"}
                    <li class="brand five columns">
                        <a href="#">
                            {brand_image}
                            <img src="{url}" alt="{title}-image" />
                            {/brand_image}
                        </a>
                        <div class="band">{brand_logos}<img src="{url}" alt="{title}-logo" />{/brand_logos}</div>
            <div class="lookbooks">
<!-- start playa fields -->
                            <div class="columns two season">
                                    {lookbook_season} <!--this is the matrix field -->
                                    <a href="{link}" title="{season}">{season}</a>
                                    {/lookbook_season}
                            </div>
            <!-- end playa fields -->

                        <div class="columns two social">
                            <div class="columns eight">
                                <div class="s1" id="fbook"><a class="icon-facebook" href="{facebook_link}" title="facebook link"></a></div>
                                <div class="s1" id="twit"><a class="icon-twitter" href="{twitter_link}" title="twitter link"></a></div>                                
                                <div class="s1" id="insta"><a class="icon-instagram" href="{instagram_link}" title="instagram link"></a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is the setup in the backend if you need to know it is in the attachment.

[image: The matrix field in the backend]

[image: The playa field inside the matrix field]

Has anyone ever had these problems before?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your matrix tag pair:

```
{lookbook_season var_prefix="mx"} <!--this is the matrix field -->
    <a href="{mx:link var_prefix='pl'}{pl:url_title}{/mx:link}" title="{mx:season}">{mx:season}</a>
{/lookbook_season}
```

To me it helps (and is sometimes required) to use var_prefix parameter to make sure you're targeting the right variable. But in your case what you're wanting I think is the url_title of the "link" playa field.

Comment: ah the season field is picked up but the url is not which is the Playa field...

Comment: I don't suppose the status is set to something other than 'open' on the channel that Link relates to?